# Where are the java swing String for me to translate?

Tags: java, swing, translation, jfilechooser, uimanager

The JFileChooser don't provide support for my language, I'd translate strings defined in the file http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/JavaUIDefaults.txt with the UIManager.put(),
but I'm not finding the popup strings ("view", "refresh" and "new folder" options when you right-click).

Does anyone know where can I find them to translate?

**--update**

The FileDialog creates a native dialog, which solves the translation problem, but leads to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467180/how-do-i-center-a-java-awt-filedialog-on-the-screen).

**--update**

Best solution for now: use the system default LAF, so the JFileChooser is system's native dialog and don't need translation. Bad I can't use Nimbus..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be `sun.swing.FilePane` that has the Strings, which are then used by `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI`.

Comment: God.. yes it is.. and is a sun's internal class.. :(
Maybe is more easy to correct the FileDialog problem (see my update)

Answer (score 1):

These are the UIManager strings for the JFileChooser context menu. This example is setting them in english.

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewActionLabelText", "Details");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewActionLabelText", "List");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.viewMenuLabelText", "View");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.refreshActionLabelText", "Refresh"));
UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderActionLabelText", "New Folder");
```