# Reset Open File Dialog Position in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

I open an open file dialog using `GetOpenFileName` function. I'm making a handler function that will center the dialog window inside the owner window. I center the dialog on `CDN_INITDONE` notification.

Currently, it seems that Windows remembers last dialog position for desktop apps and overrides my dialog coordinates. How to reset that last remembered position so that I can check centering will work for my users?

I thought about running a test using a different user or virtual machine but this isn't very convenient. Unfortunately, searching in the registry for myexecutable.exe returns nothing.

I'm running Windows 8.

Comment: Overriding the user's preference for where the dialog is located isn't exactly a great idea.  It is not impossible, call PostMessage() before you show the dialog to post a message back to yourself.  When you get it, find the dialog window back and put it where you want it.  Sample code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2576220/17034).

Comment: A CBT hook would get it done too

Comment: @HansPassant I tried a similar approach: called SetWindowPos on dialog window after a second after its appearance. It seems that open file dialog ignores both SetWindowPos and MoveWindow method calls. Window handles (hwnd) are correct - checked their titles with GetWindowText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm about a year late, but I just had to deal with this issue. What worked for me was supplying an `OFNHookProc` to `GetOpenFileName()`, then subclassing the parent of the HWND passed to the `OFNHookProc`.

After subclassing, I handle `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, and if the coordinates aren't where I think they should be, I do a `SetWindowPos()`, undo the subclass and return 0.

Edit: I should say that other methods, such as `WM_INITDIALOG` in the hook proc or `CDN_INITDONE` did not work for me whatsoever.